# Using the reference of one cell to create relative references

Tags: excel, reference, formula

My P11 cell references another cell:

```
=J14
```

And I want to reference the reference in the P11 cell in multiple other cells. EX:

```
=OFFSET(J14,0,-4)
=OFFSET(J14,0,1)
=OFFSET(J14,0,2)
```

Except the "J14" in the OFFSET formula would ideally have a reference that grabs the reference of the P11 cell because I'm going to need to change that reference every time I do it. It would therefore be helpful to grab the reference of the P11 cell so that I only need to change the reference of one cell instead of 4.

I spent about an hour googling this but I just can't seem to find anything. If you guys could help that would be great because I just can't find a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming in cell P11 you have the formula `=J14` you can use a combination of `FORMULATEXT`, `INDIRECT`, and `SUBSTITUTE` to get the cell reference. I am assuming the formula in cell P11 will only ever be a reference to a single other cell (e.g. `=J14` or `=M10` or `=N14`). If this is not true and the formula will ever be more complex than referencing one cell, this method will not work.

First we can use `=FORMULATEXT(P11)` to get the text of the formula in cell `P11`. The result of this is `=J14`. In order to be a valid cell reference we must remove the equal sign, which we can do by applying the `SUBSTITUTE` function like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(P11),"=","")
```

The result of this is `J14` which is a valid reference we can pass into the `INDIRECT` function to get what we are ultimately after.

So finally, in each of your offset formulas you would have:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(P11),"=","")),0,-4)
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(P11),"=","")),0,1)
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(P11),"=","")),0,2)
```

The benefit of this method is that you only need to change the formula in cell `P11` and it does not rely on intermediate cells.

I hope this helps, if it doesn't and you can clarify your issue I can give another try.

Comment: Wow this is perfect. Thanks so much! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: I'm having an issue now with the cells that are referenced. Is there any way to reference the actual cell that the data is being extracted from, and not the cell that is referenced in the INDIRECT formula?

Comment: Could you provide me with a quick example? I was thinking that's what I was already doing. For example, the data comes from cell J14 but the formula is in P11, we use P11 to build the reference to J14.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489178/change-the-reference-of-a-cell-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use the INDIRECT() in conjuntion:

In another empty cell, lets say Q11 you would put in the cell reference as a string `P1`.

Then the following formulas in their various cells:

```
=INDIRECT(Q11)
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(Q11),0,-4)
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(Q11),0,1)
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(Q11),0,2)
```

A couple of words about these two formulas, they are Volatile functions.  That means that they recalculate every time excel recalculates whether the data to which they refer change or not.  So if you have a sheet full of them it will make a noticeable change in the calculation times.  Only have four would not be noticeable.