# Change the reference of a cell in excel?

Tags: excel, reference, cell, box

Maybe you guys could help me because I'm stumped. Here are some pictures to help illustrate my problem:

[image]

As you can see, D1 is "referencing" B1. However, because I'm using the INDIRECT function, the actual reference is C1 and the following occurs:

[image]

The blue reference box is on C1 and not B1. Is there any way to change the blue box so that it surrounds the actual cell being referenced (B1) without actually changing which cell is referenced by the INDIRECT function (C1)?

Also, this is just an example to illustrate my problem. I don't think it's wise to post my actual sheet because I'm in a research lab. Rest assured, the INDIRECT function is necessary.

Comment: It does show the cell which you are using in your formula... it will never highlight the outcome of a calculation. And there will also be no way of doing it. Still you could use `=CELL("address",[your formula])` to get the address of your target. (If possible, try to change the referencing to `INDEX` because `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` are volatile) ;)

Comment: And what Dirk means by VOLATILE, and please correct me if I am wrong @DirkReichel, is that volatile functions recalculate every time something in the worksheet changes (possibly workbook).  A non-volatile function will only recalculate when the cells its reference change.  This means that if you are only using a volatile function a couple of times you will most likely be fine.  But if you are repeatedly reusing a volatile function, then you will notice a slow down in your worksheet.

Comment: Hmm does INDEX work with relative references?

Answer (score 0):

You technically could use conditional formatting, but the problem is you would need to add a conditional formatting formula for each one of your offset formulas.  If you are staying in the same row and there a multiple offsets this might be ok, but if your offsets are being called from all over the place and can it will become unruly.

Select your reference area in this case A1:C1 and ensure A1 is your active cell within your selection.  Go into conditional formatting and make a new formula based rule.  In the line for the formula enter the following:

```
=A1=OFFSET(INDIRECT($C1),0,1)
```

This assumes you are staying in the same row, if not then use $C$1.

now the kicker is you just have to repeat that process for every offset function you want to check.  The reason I left it as $C1 was in case the offset function was repeated row after row.

Proof of concept

[image: proof of concept]

Comment: I really dont recommend doing this as your are doubling the number of offset formulas you are using.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if I follow. How do you enter that rule into conditional formatting? There's so many options for conditional formatting.

Comment: there is only one option as far as I know that allows for formulas.  its the bottom one on the list.